# s3manager library uploading to s3 bucket won't let recipient access/open file

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I am using s3manager for golang, i am trying to upload a file to a bucket outside my account. while i successfully uploaded the file, the recipient of that bucket cannot open it.

here is my UploadInput

```
upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket:        aws.String(bucket),
    Key:           aws.String(key),
    Body:          file,
}
```

I tried adding the GrantFullControl parameter and it actually had an error on the uploader.Upload()

```
upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:        aws.String(bucket),
        Key:           aws.String(key),
        Body:          file,
        GrantFullControl: aws.String("GrantFullControl"),
    }
```

It works locally but once deployed, is there a correct way of granting permissions to the uploaded file using this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to specify to whom you are granting full control.

```golang
upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:        aws.String(bucket),
        Key:           aws.String(key),
        Body:          file,
        GrantFullControl: aws.String("Arn of user or account ID who gets access"),
    }
```

Refer [REST API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-using-rest-api.html) and the section about access permissions.

If you just want to give public access to your object or are operating only within a single account, you can also set the ACL argument to one of supported [canned ACLs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl)

For example,

```golang
upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:        aws.String(bucket),
        Key:           aws.String(key),
        Body:          file,
        ACL:           aws.String("public-read"),
    }
```

Comment: yup, it worked, but the canned ACL i used is bucket-owner-full-control 
```ACL:    aws.String("bucket-owner-full-control")```